# "These include" or "This includes"

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing a user manual and am stuck upon *these include* and *this includes*. Do I use *This includes* when there is only one thing involved? For example, "This includes normal users" and "This includes the front door". And do I use *These include* when there are two or more things? For example: "These include the lights and doors", "These include administrators and normal users".

Comment: What's the sentence that comes before? That would indicate these or this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Sam said in his comment, the crux is what **precedes** the "this/these include(s)", not what follows. As a matter of fact, "*This includes administrators and normal users*" can be just fine, depending on the context.

That said, these can still be a little tricky.  For example:

> *Several different users can change their own passwords; these include administrators, and normal users*.

The "*these include*" refers to "*several different users*."  But:

> *No users are allowed to change their own passwords; this includes administrators, and normal users*.

In this case, the "*this includes*" is singular, because it refers to the single principle that *no user is allowed to change a password*.

> *Corruption was uncovered at many levels across the organization; these include both administrators, and normal users*.

Here, "*these include*" refers back to the many *levels* where corruption was found.

However, instead of trying to figure out the correct usage, a better option would be to use the more all-encompassing **including**.  In fact, this change seems to improve the sentences:

> *Several different users can change their own passwords, including administrators and normal users*.
>
> *No users are allowed to change their own passwords; including both administrators and normal users*.
>
> *Corruption was uncovered at many levels across the organization, including administrators and normal users*.

Get rid of this **this**, and this problem goes away.

A footnote (to underscore how tricky the *this/these* choice can be): I could have said, "*In fact, these changes seem to improve the sentences...*"

Which is correct?  If I am referring to the single hint of replacing the phrase "*this includes*" with the word *including*, then "*this change seems to improve*" is appropriate.  But, if I'm referring to the three individual improvements found in each example, then "*these changes*" would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip for getting rid of decision making. But the single principle part confuses me. The sentence was first 'No users are allowed to change their own passwords', but then it became a single principle: 'No user is allowed to change a password'.

Comment: *Corruption was uncovered at many levels across the organization; **this** includes large-scale bribe-taking as well as petty pilfering*. The choice of *this/these* can actually tell the reader which antecedent is being referenced.

Comment: @fxam: it doesn't matter if you say "_no users are_," or "_no user is_;" the **this** doesn't refer to the user(s), it refers to the single rule that users can't change passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if

> there is only one thing involved

then surely use

> This includes

Check [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%20includes,these%20include&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for particular cases of use.